# При попытки записи csv файла в базу данных выдает ошибку pyodbc.ProgrammingError: Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции ";"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, csv

```py
from tkinter import*
import csv
import pyodbc


def vipoln():
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER={test}; database={test};UID={test};PWD={12345}")
    with open ('zzzz.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        columns = next(reader) 
        query = 'insert into testzodaniy({0}) values ({1})'
        query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        for data in reader:
            cursor.execute(query, data)
        cursor.commit()
        conn.close()
    

root=Tk()
root.title("Главное меню")
root.geometry("400x300")

vipolnit_btn=Button(root,text='выполнить',width=35,command=vipoln)
vipolnit_btn.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

При попытки записи csv файла в базу данных выдает ошибку:

```
cursor.execute(query, data)  
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции ";". (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Не удалось выполнить подготовку инструкций. (8180)')
```

Comment: Предлагаете угадать какие у вас данные и что пошло не так? :) Выведите `query` и `data` до `cursor.execute` и добавьте в вопрос те, что привели к ошибке (кнопка `править`)

Comment: спасибо уже помогли . да у меня данные были разделены через ; , надо было сделать так:reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется у вас в `csv` файле данные разделены через `;`, соответственно, попробуйте читать его так:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: спасибо большое . заработало